# Como carregar arquivos, pastas e subpastas utilizando php

Tags: php, upload, carregamento

Gostaria de saber se é possível carregar arquivos, pastas e subpastas utilizando PHP?
 Sei quem em java e possível fazer este tipo de carregamento, mas no php só consegui realizar upload de múltiplos arquivos.

Answer (score 2):

Através do atributo `webkitdirectory`  ou `directory` (da mesma forma que você utilize o `multiple`), você pode adicionar essa funcionalidade ao seu input file.

Exemplificando:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple name="imagens[]" />
```

Vi isso nessa resposta do SOEN:

[How to do upload folder with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008406/how-to-upload-folder-with-php)